# ConTeXt: How to change the background color and border of a Pandoc-generated blockquote?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, backgrounds, quoting, pandoc

Consider the following minimum working example containing a `blockquote` as defined in a [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)-generated document:

```
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\setupdelimitedtext
  [blockquote]
  [before={\blank[medium]},
   after={\blank[medium]},
   indentnext=no,
  ]

\starttext
\input tufte
\startblockquote
\input zapf
\stopblockquote
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

### Question

How could I obtain a light gray background for the `blockquote` with a dark red 1em-thick left vertical borderline only by changing the preamble? 
Other borders should be 0pt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the text is marked up logically within a `blockquote`
environment and pandoc includes custom headers included with the `-H` option *after* the default
ones, you can simply create an environment which displays the text
in the desired way using any mechanism which meets your needs.

I define a [`framedtext`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineframedtext) environment with the name `blockquote` and
the desired features, which is used instead of the default definition.

```
\startsetups framedsetups
  \setupwhitespace[medium]
\stopsetups


\defineframedtext
  [blockquote]
  [
    framecolor=darkred,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=lightgray,
    frame=off, 
    leftframe=on,
    rulethickness=1em,
    offset=overlay,
    loffset=2em,
    roffset=1em,
    width=\textwidth,
    setups=framedsetups,
  ]
```

which gives

[image]

Another option is to use `background` environment with the name `blockquote`. For example:

```
\definebackground
  [blockquote]
  [
    framecolor=darkred,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=lightgray,
    frame=off, 
    leftframe=on,
    rulethickness=1em,
    offset=overlay,
    leftoffset=2em,
    rightoffset=1em,
    width=\textwidth,
    setups=framedsetups,
    before=\blank,
    after=\blank,
  ]
```

which gives the same result as before, but has the advantage that the content can break across pages.

Comment: Using pandoc's `-H` option to overwrite pandoc environments is really clever.

Comment: I prefer textbackgrounds (or backgrounds) over framed as the latter does not break across pages.

Comment: @Aditya Another drawback of using `framedtext` instead of `textbackground` is that whitespace between paragraphs is not printed. On the other hand, I could `textbackground` not get that far as to print only the left frame border.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: See the edited answer to see how to add whitespace inside a framedtext and how to use background

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how to do this? I tried copying the last code block into a `blockquote.tex` text file, and then including it with `pandoc infile.md -o outfile.pdf -H blockquote.tex`, but I get an `! Undefined control sequence.
l.44 \definebackground` error.