# How to change the background color and border of a Pandoc-generated blockquote?

Tags: pandoc

This question has a possible solution, but it's for the ConTeXt writer, which I can't use.

[ConTeXt: How to change the background color and border of a Pandoc-generated blockquote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131447/context-how-to-change-the-background-color-and-border-of-a-pandoc-generated-blo?newreg=d28720d059be4f49ae4bec3457a69de5)

What would be a LaTeX solution to achieve the same?

EDIT:
pandoc version is 1.9.4.2 on a debian wheezy system.
This is the tex generated from `pandoc -V geometry:a4paper -V geometry:margin=2cm test.md -o test.tex`

```
\section{Test 1}
\subsection{Test 2}
\ldots{} this is a test.
\begin{verbatim}
    Block
    quote
    123
\end{verbatim}
\ldots{} more text.
```

I don't use a custom template.
If I put the example (`\startsetups framedsetups` ...) from the link in a file framedtext.tex and include it via -H, I get (and yes, I know I'd have to change the environment `verbatim`instead of `blockquote`):

```
>$ pandoc -H framedtext.tex -V geometry:a4paper -V geometry:margin=2cm test.md -o test.pdf
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.39 \startsetups
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please add the code generated by Pandoc?

Comment: Is your problem how to change the result LaTeX file, or how to make pandoc create what you want?

Comment: The latter. The link at the top has a solution, but it's for ConTeXt. I need a solution for LaTeX, i.e. a file I could include via the -H option.

Answer (score 12):

You simply need to use LaTeX code if you are going to produce a LaTeX document. A very simple example:

```
% mystylefile.pandoc
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black}
% redefine the 'quote' environment to use this 'myquote' environment
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{myquote}}{\end{myquote}}
```

Then the markdown file:

```markdown
<!-- test.md -->
This is not a block quote.                   

>    This question has a possible solution, but it's for the ConTeXt writer, which I can't use.
>    ConTeXt: How to change the background color and border of a Pandoc-generated blockquote?
>    What would be a LaTeX solution to achieve the same?

This is not a block quote.
```

Then the `pandoc` line:

```sh
pandoc -H mystylefile.pandoc -V geometry:a4paper -V geometry:margin=2cm test.md -o test.tex
```

If you have not modified the `latex.template` file (see [here](https://gist.github.com/michaelt/1017790) for some hints how to modify it), you should end up with a `.tex` file that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% Note: I have cut out all the default stuff that ends up here
% to highlight what the effects are of including `mystylefile.sty`

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{myquote}}{\end{myquote}}

% Other default stuff removed

\begin{document}

This is not a block quote.

\begin{quote}
This question has a possible solution, but it's for the ConTeXt writer,
which I can't use. ConTeXt: How to change the background color and
border of a Pandoc-generated blockquote? What would be a LaTeX solution
to achieve the same?
\end{quote}

This is not a block quote.

\end{document}
```

This is the quick hack. The better solution is to create a `latex.template` file and use that (if I remember correctly, that's what the `-D` switch is for).

Answer (score 10):

Using [jon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337587/17868) and the latest version of pandoc, I was able to put the commands in the front matter of the markdown itself using `header-includes:` as follows:

`metadata.yml`:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \newtcolorbox{myquote}{colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black}
- \renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{myquote}}{\end{myquote}}
```

Use in markdown:

```
> Here's a blockquote
```

PDF result:

[image]