# How to add background color to the typing environment?

Tags: context, pandoc

How can I add background to verbatim code blocks without adding extra vertical space?

I am writing in Pandocs markdown, then converting to .tex with `pandoc.exe -t context`, then to PDF with `context.exe`. Markdown verbatim code blocks are by default converted by Pandoc to the typing environment. That is, placed between

```
\starttyping
my code
\stoptyping
```

I want to add colored background to the text in the typing environment by using `\setuptyping` (or similar preamble command). I have tried to use
`\textbackground`, but I am not happy with the extra vertical space that is added.

### PDF output

#### 1. No \textbackgound

[image: PDF without \textbackground]

#### 2. \textbackgound

[image: PDF with \textbackground]

### Markdown source

```
# Usage pattern

The usage pattern of MyCLI is the following:

    MyCLI OPTION PARAMETER

Options can be either in short form (one-letter) or long-form (whole words).
```

### Pandoc output

```
\chapter[title={Usage pattern},reference={usage-pattern}]

The usage pattern of MyCLI is the following:

\starttyping
MyCLI OPTION PARAMETER
\stoptyping

Options can be either in short form (one-letter) or long-form (whole words).
```

### Context preamble

```
\definetextbackground[code][
    width=\textwidth,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=lightgray,
    frame=off
    ]

\setuptyping[ % layout of code blocks
    keeptogether=yes,
    lines=yes,
    bodyfont=10pt,
    before={\starttextbackground[code]},
    after={\stoptextbackground},
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was already answered in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131447/context-how-to-change-the-background-color-and-border-of-a-pandoc-generated-blo?newreg=d28720d059be4f49ae4bec3457a69de5). The `\definebackground` macro is the solution I was looking for.